# Is there any way to cache query results from rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using the users, posts, grants table in my application. I try to build an index api for posts. Below are my model, controller codes.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts,
             through: :grants,
             source: :resource,
             source_type: 'Post'
end
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users,
             through: :grants,
             source: :grantee,
             source_type: 'User'
end
```

I am trying to build a api like `{base_url}\posts?slugs="test-1,test-2,test-3"`. Below is my controller codes.

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    reder json: { posts: posts_hash }
  end
  
  private

  def posts
    @_posts ||= current_user.posts.where(code: params['slugs'])
  end

  def posts_hash
    puts posts.last

    # again running query to fetch data

    posts.each_with_object({}) do |post, hash|
      next unless post

      hash[post.slug] = PostPresenter.present(post, current_user: Current.user, path_info: Current.path_info)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem I am facing, when I am calling the api, within the `each_with_object` loop posts query running again though I used memoization. I want to understand why this is happening and how to solve the issue by running a single query.

Comment: Pass the array of slugs to `posts.where(slug: array_of_slugs)` then loop the results to populate the hash. A single query should be performed.

Comment: @rezvans Thanks solve the problem. But can you tell me why this is happening? Even if I do call `posts` again within the same method It's calling query again.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I am facing, when I am calling the api, within the each_with_object loop posts query running again though I used memoization.

You've encountered ActiveRecord's lazy loading here. When you call `.where`, `.order` and so on, it doesn't make database queries. It only changes a "query object" by adding options to it. It's only when you start iterating that query object and ActiveRecord needs actual data, it sends the DB query.

For example, you can fix your double query by iterating right away. With `.to_a`, for example.

```
@_posts ||= current_user.posts.where(code: params['slugs']).to_a
```